# Express $(A_{j})_{j\in\mathbb{N}}\subset f^{-1}(\mathcal{A'}) \iff ?$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

> Let $f:X\to X^{'}$ be a map and let $\mathcal{A}'$ be a
> $\sigma$-algebra in $X'$. Then
> $$\mathcal{A}:=f^{-1}(\mathcal{A'}):=\{f^{-1}(A'):A'\in\mathcal{A'}\}$$
> Is a $\sigma-$algebra in X.

My question:
when I would like to prove the following statement:
$$(A_{j})_{j\in\mathbb{N}}\subset f^{-1}(\mathcal{A'})\implies \mathop{\bigcup}_{j\in\mathbb{N}}A_{j}\in f^{-1}(\mathcal{A'})$$

==============================================

I don't know how to express this $(A_{j})_{j\in\mathbb{N}}\subset f^{-1}(\mathcal{A'})$ formally.

Is that $$(A_{j})_{j\in\mathbb{N}}\subset f^{-1}(\mathcal{A'})\iff \exists (A^{'}_{j})_{j\in\mathbb{N}}\subset \mathcal{A}':A_{j}=f^{-1}(A^{'}_{j})$$
true ?

==============================================

after that everything goes smoothly

$$\mathop{\bigcup}_{j\in\mathbb{N}}A_{j}=\mathop{\bigcup}_{j\in\mathbb{N}}f^{-1}(A^{'}_{j})=f^{-1}\left(\mathop{\bigcup}_{j\in\mathbb{N}}A^{'}_{j}\right) \in f^{-1}(\mathcal{A'})\; \text{as}\; \mathop{\bigcup}_{j\in\mathbb{N}}A^{'}_{j}\in \mathcal{A'}$$

Comment: I believe it follows immediately from the fact that for any function $f: X \to X'$, $f^{-1}(\bigcup_{i <\omega} A_i) = \bigcup_{i < \omega} f^{-1}(A_i)$ for any $A_i \subset X'$

Comment: What you have done is perfect.

Comment: Thank you, but my question is to know how to express $(A_{j})_{j\in\mathbb{N}}\subset f^{-1}(\mathcal{A'})$